# matplotlib legend_elements returns empty

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following scatter plot, where I define different colors for edges and markers:

```
    label_colors = [mcolors.to_rgba('rgbkmy'[lbl]) for lbl in list(labels)]
    pred_colors = [mcolors.to_rgba('rgbkmy'[lbl]) for lbl in list(preds)]

    classes = ['Agents','AI','DB','IR','ML','HCI']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    scatter = plt.scatter(X_embedded[:, 0], X_embedded[:, 1], c=label_colors, edgecolors=pred_colors, linewidths=2)


    legend1 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(),
                        loc="lower left", title="Classes")
    ax.add_artist(legend1)

    if(is_show):plt.show()
```

Unfortunatlly, `scatter.legend_elements()` returns an empty list, where if I change it to `c=labels` which is a list of integers I am able to plot the legend, but then `edgecolors` breaks, because `edgecolors` needs `RGBA` as input.

The goal for me is to have a legend with the colors as appear in `label_colors,edgecolors`, and that the label itself in the legend will correspond to `classes` (0-> Agents, etc.)
This is the current plot (legend empty)
[image]

Comment: you need to add labels to your plt.scatter.  It can be a list, etc.  Check out https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html and https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html

Comment: `legend_elements()` can only be used when the scatter properties are mapped from an array. If they are set as individual colors (like `"red"`), it's not useful at all.

Comment: OK, is it possible to achieve such functionality? Different colors for labels and preds with the rgbkmy coloring I defined? (and not explicitly define rgba)

Comment: Yes. You would create a colormap with those colors and use it.

Comment: Here I only have one scatter plot with multiple labels, I did not understand from the examples how can that be achieved from the links above:)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've changed it to be rgba (edited in the question) and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked eventually

```
    classes = ['Agents', 'AI', 'DB', 'IR', 'ML', 'HCI']
    class_colours = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'm', 'y']
    recs = []
    for i in range(0, len(class_colours)):
        recs.append(mpatches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=class_colours[i]))
    plt.legend(recs, classes, loc=4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer by DsCpp is more or less the way to go, in that you have to create custom patches and then pass them to your legend. One way to streamline this is to create a custom wrapper for the scatter function and then the properties can be passed as kwargs like so:

```py
def scatter_wrapper(ax, x, y, **kwargs):
    ax.scatter(x, y, **kwargs)
    return Line2D([0],[0], linewidth=0, **kwargs)
```

And then in your main function

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patches = []
patches.append(scatter_wrapper(ax, x, y, c=c, label="Some data", marker='s'))
ax.legend(handles=patches)
```

Just means you can do your plotting and patch generation in one place.